# Keyboard language not setting correctly at startup in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I have a clean install of Windows 10 English and configured it to have English UI language but with Portuguese as default input method.

The problem is that at startup, after login, the keyboard language is being set to English. But if I log out, and log in again, then is set correctly to Portuguese.

Anyone have any idea of what might be wrong?

Here are some screenshots of my settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the problem of WINDOWS 10 i face on many of different computers.
It always revers back to **English (United Kingdom)**. Very frustrating... 
I dont know permanent solution, but as a temporary solution, you should add English(UNITED KINGDOM), then remove it again. Then try to set your desired language as default.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this problem.

I removed all languages, except English.  Then went to Options, and in 'Input method' removed all existent, then added Portuguese as input method, and leaving it as the only option.

After that, all work as I expected. English as UI language, and Portuguese as keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after the Windows 10 Anniversary update in August 2016. My language preferences and lists were all correct, but the computer kept starting with English as the input method. When I clicked or right-clicked on EN to change it, the little menu did not pop up like it is supposed to.

Eventually I worked out that the problem was to do with Stoic Joker's T-Clock 2010 x64. I uninstalled that and replaced it with a different version, https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock, and that solved the problem.